# Can I assign values in two select elements to one variable?

Tags: php, sql, variables

I am fairly new to php and I am having all sorts of problems with this code basically I want to add time values from 2 select options to one variable and then store that varible as TIME in my DB. I am not clear on how to post a variable that contains two values its probably achievable through arrays but I have tried and lets just say its been fruitless please see the code below.

Also suggestions will be more useful if its via PHP, see image for the form.

```
 <?php


 //connect to db
 include 'connect.php';

 //This is the directory where images will be saved 
 $event_type = $_POST['event_type']; 
 $title = strip_tags($_POST['title']); 
 $description = strip_tags($_POST['description']);
 $date = strip_tags ($_POST['date']); 
 $stime = $_POST['stime']);
 $etime = $_POST['etime'])
 $add1  = strip_tags($_POST['address1']);
 $add2  = strip_tags($_POST['address2']);
 $city = strip_tags($_POST['city']); 
 $postcode  = strip_tags($_POST['postcode']);
 $country = strip_tags($_POST['country']); 
 $tick  = strip_tags($_POST['tkqty']);
 $price = strip_tags($_POST['price']);
 $now = time();

 $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
 $image_tmpname = addslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
 $image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);



 if (strtotime($date) < $now) {
echo $errormsg = "that date is not valid";}



 if ($image_size==FALSE)
echo "That is not an image";
else 
{
if ($image_name)


$target = "uploaded/$image_name"; 
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$target);
$user = $_SESSION['user_id'];

mysql_query ("INSERT into events VALUES('','$event_type','$title','$description','$date','$stime','$etime','$target','$add1','$add2','$city','$postcode','$country','$tick','$price','$user')");

  //Tells you if its all ok 
  echo "<h2> Event Add Successful</h2>";
  echo "Your event : ".$title." is now live, please return to <a href='manage_event.php'>manage           event</a> area. ";
  }


?>
```

[image]

Comment: `strip_tags` is NOT the correct way to protect yourself against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating two new dates from your time entries (hours and minutes, the rest is zero).

Add each new date to the existing date, capture both results, and then you'll have a "datetime from" and a "datetime to" which you can store in your database like datetime fields.